# Magento2: Catalog PDF generator

Tags: magento2, pdf

We have install free extension catalog pdf geenrator:
https://snm-portal.com/magento2-pdf-publication.html

movie with issue: https://streamable.com/h4g99

But in tab "Templates" we get issue:
https://prnt.sc/r55kj6

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Element 'column', attribute 'component': The attribute 'component' is not allowed.
Line: 102

Element 'column', attribute 'sortOrder': The attribute 'sortOrder' is not allowed.
Line: 102

Element 'settings': This element is not expected.
Line: 103


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Element 'column', attribute 'component': The attribute 'component' is not allowed.
Line: 102

Element 'column', attribute 'sortOrder': The attribute 'sortOrder' is not allowed.
Line: 102

Element 'settings': This element is not expected.
Line: 103

#0 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/DomMerger.php(393): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->createDomDocument('<?xml version="...')
#1 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(60): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->merge('<?xml version="...')
#2 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(47): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->readFiles(Array)
#3 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\FileCollector\AggregatedFileCollector), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Converter), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger))
#4 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#6 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/ReaderFactory.php(40): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#7 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(242): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\ReaderFactory->create(Array)
#8 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(258): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->getReader('snmportal_publi...')
#9 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(166): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('snmportal_publi...')
#10 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('snmportal_publi...')
#11 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(124): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('snmportal_publi...', NULL, Array)
#12 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure), 'snmportal_publi...', Array, Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor))
#13 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#14 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(327): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context))
#15 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements()
#16 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#17 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks()
#18 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(197): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#19 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php(217): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build()
#20 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/app/code/Snmportal/Publication/Controller/Adminhtml/Templates/Index.php(55): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->getTitle()
#21 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Snmportal\Publication\Controller\Adminhtml\Templates\Index->execute()
#22 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#23 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Snmportal\Publication\Controller\Adminhtml\Templates\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#25 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Snmportal\\Publi...', 'dispatch', Object(Snmportal\Publication\Controller\Adminhtml\Templates\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
#26 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Snmportal\Publication\Controller\Adminhtml\Templates\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Snmportal\\Publi...', 'dispatch', Object(Snmportal\Publication\Controller\Adminhtml\Templates\Index\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')
#29 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Snmportal\Publication\Controller\Adminhtml\Templates\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Snmportal\Publication\Controller\Adminhtml\Templates\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#31 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Snmportal/Publication/Controller/Adminhtml/Templates/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Snmportal\Publication\Controller\Adminhtml\Templates\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#32 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Snmportal\Publication\Controller\Adminhtml\Templates\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#33 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#34 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#35 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')
#36 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#37 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#38 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#39 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#40 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#41 /home/b2b/domains/b2bstyle.pl/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#42 {main}
```

Anyone help how to solve?

Comment: In which page your are getting this error?

Comment: Please check this movie: https://streamable.com/h4g99

Comment: Could you share the menu.xml code.

Comment: Where is located this file?

Comment: From here you can download all files extension:  https://files.fm/u/8vxvrcqp

Comment: It is not opening for me..

Comment: can you please try again? https://files.fm/u/8vxvrcqp

Comment: Nope it's not opening up for me..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104698/discussion-between-aravind-and-sylvester).